# Popup showing only on the first page of the website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a website that is build with php, and I added a popup box in the index.php file.

I have an onload method in the body tag which display the popup on the page load, but that is triggered on every page of the website.

I tried to add a condition:

```
if (document.URL == "mymainpage")
```

but it seems that when I go to the next page, it is triggered and when I want to close the popup then it checks again the url and it changed so it wont close the popup.

What is the best method to show the popup only the 1st time the user access the website?

P.S.: I am using this code in the index.php file:

```
<body<?php echo $body_attr;?>>

<?php
session_start();
$body_attr = "";
if(!isset($_SESSION["popup_shown"]))
{
    $body_attr = " onload=\"show('popupContainer')\"";
    $_SESSION["popup_shown"] = true;
}
?>
<script>

function show(id) {

       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';

    }
</script>
<!-- ============== THE POPUP ======================= -->
<div id="popupContainer" style="display:block; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); height:100%; width:100%; z-index:999;">
    <div id="popup" style="border:2px solid white; font-size:20px; line-height:25px; text-align:center; width:75%; margin:0 auto; background-color:#18af8e; position:relative; top:35%; padding:15px; padding-bottom:0px; border-radius:20px;">
        <p style="color:white;">Din cauza perioadei foarte aglomerate si a vacantei de sarbatori, comenzile primite dupa <b>20 Decembrie</b> vor fi onorate in ianuarie. 
<br></br>
Va multumim pentru intelegere si va dorim <b>Sarbatori Fericite!</b></p>
        <button onclick="show('popupContainer')" style="display:inline; position:absolute; top:-30px; left:100%; padding:0 5px 2px 5px; border-radius:50%; border:2px solid black; background:none; font-weight:bold">x</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the best method to show the popup only the 1st time the user access the website? Using sessions/cookie

Answer (score 1):

Why not use cookies with PHP?

```
$popup = "<div class='popup'>This popup is awesome</div>";

if($_COOKIE["PopupShown"] != true){
    echo $popup;
}

setcookie("PopupShown", true);
```

For example..

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: sessions are more save since they also work when people got cookies disabled in their browsers (if not they work with cookies anyways).

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["popup_shown"]))
{
    echo "//javascript and/or html code to show the popup";
    $_SESSION["popup_shown"] = true;
}
```

**update:** according to your comments, just change what's in your `<body>` tag then:

```
session_start();
$body_attr = "";
if(!isset($_SESSION["popup_shown"]))
{
    $body_attr = " onload=\"show('divid')\"";
    $_SESSION["popup_shown"] = true;
}
```

in your html:

```
<body<?php echo $body_attr;?>>
```

**note:** `session_start()` has to be called before any other output occurs!

Comment: Maybe a session_start(); before will help :D

Comment: @MarcoMura that would help if you are not familiar with sessions at least ;) thanks.

Comment: We do not know what the OP knows so i think it always better to specify all the code needed ;)

Comment: @MarcoMura yeah, that's right.

Comment: The problem with this is that I have to close the popup clicking on the x. And it won't work because it is set to true. I have somehow to wait for the x to be clicked.

Comment: @FlorinPop i don't really understand what you want to achieve then. you want to show the popup on every page as long as it hasn't been closed once by clicking on its "x" ?

Comment: I have a div which contains the popup. On the page load, as I said in the body tag I have: onload="show('divid')", which calls the function that shows the div. And I also have a button in the div that has the "x" string and an onclick method: onclick="show('divid')"; so, on the button click, the popup is hideing. The problem is that if the user navigates through the page, everytime he clicks a navigation tab, the popup is showing. I only want that popup to show 1st time it enters the website.

Comment: @FlorinPop i just updated my answer according to your needs.

Comment: It is not working... Still on each tab, the popup appears

Comment: @FlorinPop then there might be some other problems. hard to say without seeing more of your code. but it's really quite simple to achieve what you want. maybe show us your full code regarding your issue.

Comment: @northkildonan I uploaded the code.

Comment: @FlorinPop yes, i already see the problem. `session_start();` has to be called before ANY output is happening. so put it on the top of your file! your PHP warning level has to be on a really low setting, otherwise you would have got error-messages about this.

Comment: Still showing when I change tabs :( and I put it in the beggining of the file.

Comment: @FlorinPop yeah, cause the default-setting for your div is `display:block;` - in your html-code just change it to `display:none;`. so your popup is hidden by default and only shown by the function which you call onload of your body.

Comment: if I do that, it's not showing at all :| idk why.